# Calculate $P(b,c,a)$ if I only have a distribution probability table of $P(a,b,c)$

Tags: probability

I have to calculate this:

$P(b|c,a)$

I think $P(b|c,a) = P(b,c,a) / P(c,a)$

If I have this distribution probability table:

[image]

How can I calculate $P(b,c,a)$ if I have $P(a,b,c)$?

And I have also to calculate $P(c,a)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an instance where the notation gets in the way of Understanding. Using $A$, $B$, and $C$ to denote *events*, what the lines of the OP's table are telling us is

\begin{align}
P(A\cap B \cap C) &= 0.03\\
P(A\cap B \cap C^c) &= 0.12\\
P(A\cap B^c \cap C) &= 0.07\\
\ddots\\
P(A^c\cap B^c \cap C^c) &= 0.18
\end{align} 
where the superscript $\,^c$ denotes complementation.  Now, the event that the OP is interested in is $P(B\cap C\cap A)$ which by a miracle of modern mathematics just happens to equal $P(A\cap B \cap C)$ whose value is specified as being $0.03$, that is, *no* calculation is required to find the OP's $P(b,c,a)$; its value is the same as the OP's $P(a, b, c)$ which the OP knows.  Similarly, $P(c, a)$ is the same as $P(a,c)$ or in more useful notation, $$P(C\cap A) = P(A\cap C) = P(A\cap B \cap C) + P(A\cap B^c \cap C)$$
which is easily found as long as the notation allows us to see the forest instead of the trees.